# spring-mvc-project hello-world

Tags: spring-mvc, sts-springsourcetoolsuite, springsource

I use SpringSource Tool Suite sts to start a hello world example about MVC.

> File -> New -> Spring Template Project -> then choose Spring MVC Project

I add Project Name: `helloworld`
and specify the top-level package as `com.helloworld.myapp`

then finish.

now I try to run the application and choose Run on Server
and it always shows me the everlasting screen that says: The requested resource (`/helloworld/`) is not available.

server shows the following:

> ```
> Nov 30, 2011 4:06:53 PM com.springsource.tcserver.security.PropertyDecoder <init> INFO: tc
> ```
>
> Runtime property decoder using memory-based key Nov 30, 2011 4:06:53
>   PM com.springsource.tcserver.security.PropertyDecoder  INFO:
>   tcServer Runtime property decoder has been initialized in 183 ms Nov
>   30, 2011 4:06:53 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init INFO:
>   Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"] Nov 30, 2011 4:06:53 PM
>   com.springsource.tcserver.serviceability.rmi.JmxSocketListener init
>   INFO: Started up JMX registry on 127.0.0.1:6969 in 63 ms Nov 30, 2011
>   4:06:53 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load INFO:
>   Initialization processed in 693 ms Nov 30, 2011 4:06:53 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal INFO: Starting
>   service Catalina Nov 30, 2011 4:06:53 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal INFO: Starting
>   Servlet Engine: VMware vFabric tc Runtime
>   2.6.1.RELEASE/7.0.20.B.RELEASE Nov 30, 2011 4:06:53 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor INFO:
>   Deploying configuration descriptor insight.xml from
>   D:\springsource\vfabric-tc-server-developer-2.6.1.RELEASE\spring-insight-instance\conf\Catalina\localhost
>   Nov 30, 2011 4:06:53 PM
>   com.springsource.insight.collection.tcserver.ltw.TomcatWeavingInsightClassLoader
>   start INFO: Context [localhost|insight] will not be woven Nov 30, 2011
>   4:06:54 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log INFO:
>   Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext Nov 30, 2011 4:07:04 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log INFO: Initializing
>   Spring FrameworkServlet 'Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet' Nov 30, 2011
>   4:07:06 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
>   INFO: Deploying web application directory manager Nov 30, 2011 4:07:06
>   PM
>   com.springsource.insight.collection.tcserver.ltw.TomcatWeavingInsightClassLoader
>   start INFO: Context [localhost|manager] will not be woven Nov 30, 2011
>   4:07:06 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
>   INFO: Deploying web application directory ROOT Nov 30, 2011 4:07:06 PM
>   com.springsource.insight.collection.tcserver.ltw.TomcatWeavingInsightClassLoader
>   start INFO: Context [localhost|ROOT] will not be woven Nov 30, 2011
>   4:07:06 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start INFO: Starting
>   ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"] Nov 30, 2011 4:07:06 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start INFO: Server startup in
>   12820 ms Nov 30, 2011 4:07:56 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor INFO:
>   Deploying configuration descriptor EchoSpringMVC.xml from
>   D:\springsource\vfabric-tc-server-developer-2.6.1.RELEASE\spring-insight-instance\conf\Catalina\localhost
>   Nov 30, 2011 4:07:56 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.SetContextPropertiesRule begin WARNING:
>   [SetContextPropertiesRule]{Context} Setting property 'source' to
>   'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:EchoSpringMVC' did not find a matching
>   property. Nov 30, 2011 4:07:56 PM
>   com.springsource.insight.collection.tcserver.ltw.TomcatWeavingInsightClassLoader
>   start INFO: Context [localhost|EchoSpringMVC] will not be woven Nov
>   30, 2011 4:07:56 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext
>   listenerStart SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to
>   listener instance of class
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Level    at
>   org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getSingleton(LoggerFactory.java:230)  at
>   org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind(LoggerFactory.java:121)  at
>   org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.java:112)
>     at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:275)
>     at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:248)    at
>   org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory.getInstance(SLF4JLogFactory.java:155)
>     at
>   org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory.getInstance(SLF4JLogFactory.java:131)
>     at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:272)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:191)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4723)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5226)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5221)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.log4j.Level  at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1678)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1523)
>     ... 18 more
>
> Nov 30, 2011 4:07:56 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext
>   startInternal SEVERE: Error listenerStart Nov 30, 2011 4:07:56 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal SEVERE: Context
>   [/EchoSpringMVC] startup failed due to previous errors Nov 30, 2011
>   4:07:56 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log INFO:
>   Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext Nov 30, 2011 4:07:56 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStop SEVERE:
>   Exception sending context destroyed event to listener instance of
>   class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
>   java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextDestroyed(ContextLoaderListener.java:80)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4763)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$4.run(StandardContext.java:5473)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) Caused by:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory could not be
>   successfully initialized. See also
>   http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#unsuccessfulInit  at
>   org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:282)     at
>   org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:248)     at
>   org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory.getInstance(SLF4JLogFactory.java:155)
>     at
>   org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory.getInstance(SLF4JLogFactory.java:131)
>     at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:272)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextCleanupListener.(ContextCleanupListener.java:43)
>     ... 4 more

Where do I go wrong? 
Please help.

Answer (score 1):

I've solved changing log4j 1.2.15 with 1.2.16 in pom.xml

New dependency look like this

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.16</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
            <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
            <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
            <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

That's all

Comment: I also have version listed as `1.2.15`. But when I change it to `1.2.16` and save the file, it changes back to `1.2.15`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are having this exception:

https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS-2128

Your code will run fine.  This is a caching problem with WTP (Web Tools Project).  A clean build should remove the error.

Comment: okay, thank you very much I went to
project-> clean
and that error does not appear again,

but again when I run the application
it goes to this address inside sts
http://localhost:8080/helloworld/WEB-INF/views/home.jsp

and also it gives the same error

description The requested resource (/helloworld/WEB-INF/views/home.jsp) is not available.

Comment: maybe it will be good to mention to you that the sever shows the following errors:
`Nov 30, 2011 4:07:56 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Level


Nov 30, 2011 4:07:56 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStop
SEVERE: Exception sending context destroyed event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener`